# Accessing/Adding to a 2D C++ array using inline assembly

Tags: inline-assembly

I'm trying to create an encryption/decryption program using c++ and assembly. I was originally using 3 different arrays, the original string, the encrypted string, and the decrypted string. I'm now trying to convert this to a 2D array and I'm having trouble adding an encrypted character to the second line of the array.

```
  __asm
  {   
         push    eax                        
         push    ebx                        
         push    ecx                        
         push    edx                        

         xor     ebx, ebx                   
         jmp     checkend                   

forloop1: add ebx, 1                         

checkend: cmp ebx, aLength                   
         jge endfor1                        

         movzx   ecx, byte ptr[Chars + ebx] 
         lea     eax, EKey                  
         push    ecx                        
         mov     edi, eax                   
         movzx   eax, byte ptr[eax]         
         and     eax, 0x3f                  
         rol     al, 1                      
         mov     byte ptr[edi], al          
         cmp     eax, 0x00                  
         jnz     zerocheck                  
         mov     eax, 0x09                  
zerocheck:mov     edx, eax                   
         pop     eax                        
         sub     eax, edx                   
         rol     al, 1                      
         not     al                         
         mov     byte ptr [Chars + ebx * 2], al       // this line here
         jmp     forloop1                   

endfor1:                                     

         pop     edx                        
         pop     ecx                        
         pop     ebx                        
         pop     eax                        
  }
return;
```

I can read in the first row fine, which is where the string entered is stored. I've marked the line where I'm trying to get the encrypted character to be stored in the second line the array but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. The [Chars + ebx * 2] is what isn't working. I know that the 2 on the end isn't the correct value, can anyone tell me what value I should be adding/multiplying on the end to get to the second line of the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it tagged with c++?

Comment: Because I'm trying to use a C++ array

Comment: Then it is unclear what you're asking. I see assembler code. I can't see a question. I see a c++ tag but I can't see c++ code.

Comment: Okay I've removed the c++ tag

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working. All I had to do was add this line of code first;

```
mov edx, aLength
```

Where aLength is the length of the array, and then use that to get the second line in the array like so;

```
mov byte ptr [Chars + ebx + edx], al
```